# Don't understand how to make different firebird.conf file for single instances

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

i need to create a second instance on my server machine running Firebird 2.5.9 SuperServer and set it to listen on a different port, and set the CPU affinity mask to use another core. I can't understand how to create different firebird.conf file for the different instances. I have to name it in a different way? I did all the instructions like the tutorial on this link, but cannot make it work.
**http://www.destructor.de/firebird/multiinstance.htm**

I expect to have multiple instances of Firebird SuperServer running on different ports, but point to the same users db.

Comment: What you want is not possible. You cannot use two SuperServer instances to access the same database. SuperServer uses an exclusive lock on the databases it uses, you'd need to use SuperClassic or Classic (in which case, using multiple instances is not really needed). In any case, if you want to have multiple instances, you need to install them to separate directories, and when configuring, make sure to remove the comment mark `#` before the config option. If that doesn't work, please provide a [mre] and be explicit in describing the problems you have.

Comment: In any case, this isn't a programming problem, so not really on-topic for Stack Overflow. Consider asking on [Database Administratores](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) or on the [firebird-support list](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support).